# SQL help for selecting most recent non-Null value for a unique plant

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a SQL Server table with data on various factories (plants), with rows identified by a root plant ID, and a sub plant ID.  The root ID is the same for the facility for its entire life.  And the sub ID is added each time the plant data is changed with the regulatory agency.

Sometimes when the plant data was re-filed with the regulator, only the changed data was submitted, and other fields were left blank (Null).

I'm looking for an elegant way to write a query that will return all of the data from the most recent sub ID record, except that for Capacity, it will pull the most recent sub for which a non-Null Capacity was actually specified.

Assume that these are the fields in the Plant table:

- RecordId (primary key)
- RootId
- SubId
- Fuel
- Capacity

Here is the SQL for selecting the data for the most recent SubId:

```
SELECT p1.* FROM Plant as p1
WHERE 
    p1.SubId = (
            SELECT TOP 1 p2.SubId FROM Plant as p2 
            WHERE p1.RootId = p2.RootId
            ORDER BY p2.SubId DESC)
```

I've been thinking about this for a while, but haven't come up with an approach.  Even just a push in the right direction would be appreciated.  Here is some SQL code to generate sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE Plant (
    RecordId  INTEGER       PRIMARY KEY,
    RootId    VARCHAR(12)   not null,
    SubID     INTEGER    not null,
    Fuel      INTEGER   not null,
    Capacity  DECIMAL(10,4)
);


INSERT INTO Plant 
VALUES 
(451, 'PLT03-39', 3, 1, 4399.67),
(471, 'PLT03-39', 4, 1, 4399.67),
(1809, 'PLT03-39', 5, 1, 4399.67),
(4888, 'PLT03-39', 6, 1, Null),
(6111, 'PLT03-39', 7, 1, Null),
(450, 'PLT03-40', 3, 1, 15531.67),
(472, 'PLT03-40', 4, 1, Null),
(1810, 'PLT03-40', 5, 1, 14767.61),
(4882, 'PLT03-40', 6, 1, Null),
(6113, 'PLT03-40', 7, 1, Null),
(454, 'PLT03-41', 5, 1, 23726.34),
(455, 'PLT03-41', 6, 1, 23726.34),
(469, 'PLT03-41', 7, 1, 23726.34),
(1807, 'PLT03-41', 8, 1, 22850.96),
(4884, 'PLT03-41', 9, 1, 22850.96),
(6110, 'PLT03-41', 10, 1, 22850.96),
(452, 'PLT03-42', 3, 1, 9120.65),
(470, 'PLT03-42', 4, 1, Null),
(1808, 'PLT03-42', 5, 1, 9120.65),
(4883, 'PLT03-42', 6, 1, 9120.65),
(6109, 'PLT03-42', 7, 1, Null),
(449, 'PLT03-43', 4, 1, 7923.96),
(474, 'PLT03-43', 5, 1, 7923.96),
(1811, 'PLT03-43', 6, 1, 7357.24),
(4881, 'PLT03-43', 7, 1, Null),
(5107, 'PLT03-43', 7, 1, 7711.44),
(5133, 'PLT03-43', 7, 1, Null),
(6112, 'PLT03-43', 8, 1, 7711.44),
(98, 'PLT05-25', 2, 18, 26.565),
(528, 'PLT05-25', 2, 18, 26033.7),
(139, 'PLT05-25', 2, 18, 26565),
(380, 'PLT05-25', 2, 18, Null),
(381, 'PLT05-25', 2, 18, 51854.88),
(7398, 'PLT06-143', 0, 18, 4091.01),
(4112, 'PLT06-143', 1, 18, 4091.01),
(5309, 'PLT06-143', 2, 18, 4091.01),
(73982, 'PLT06-143', 2, 18, 4091.01),
(73981, 'PLT06-143', 3, 18, Null),
(7397, 'PLT06-145', 0, 18, 4091.01),
(73971, 'PLT06-145', 1, 18, 4091.01),
(4109, 'PLT06-145', 1, 18, Null),
(5314, 'PLT06-145', 2, 18, 4091.01),
(73972, 'PLT06-145', 2, 18, Null),
(73973, 'PLT06-145', 3, 18, 4091.01),
(177, 'PLT06-342', 2, 1, 35420),
(1307, 'PLT06-342', 3, 1, 30360),
(5946, 'PLT06-342', 4, 1, 30360),
(6220, 'PLT06-342', 5, 1, Null),
(13264, 'PLT06-342', 6, 1, Null),
(1312, 'PLT06-344', 2, 1, 15180),
(5106, 'PLT06-344', 3, 1, 15180),
(5945, 'PLT06-344', 4, 1, 15180),
(6218, 'PLT06-344', 5, 1, Null),
(10550, 'PLT06-344', 6, 1, 10120),
(13271, 'PLT06-344', 7, 1, 10120),
(2724, 'PLT06-87', 2, 6, 143.451),
(5039, 'PLT06-87', 3, 6, 143.451),
(5886, 'PLT06-87', 4, 6, Null),
(10586, 'PLT06-87', 5, 6, 143.451),
(22759, 'PLT06-87', 6, 6, Null),
(158, 'PLT07-234', 1, 18, 21274.77),
(341, 'PLT07-234', 2, 18, 21274.77),
(7813, 'PLT07-234', 3, 18, 21274.77),
(24562, 'PLT07-234', 4, 18, Null),
(24584, 'PLT07-234', 4, 18, 2488.508),
(5965, 'PLT07-328', 2, 1, 19607.5),
(6073, 'PLT07-328', 2, 1, 19607.5),
(5996, 'PLT07-328', 2, 1, 19607.5),
(6644, 'PLT07-328', 3, 1, 19607.5),
(6701, 'PLT07-328', 3, 1, Null),
(7664, 'PLT07-328', 4, 1, Null),
(227, 'PLT07-39', 2, 18, 50347),
(1269, 'PLT07-39', 3, 18, 50258.45),
(1821, 'PLT07-39', 4, 18, 50258.45),
(1976, 'PLT07-39', 4, 18, 50258.45),
(5282, 'PLT07-39', 5, 18, Null),
(374, 'PLT08-25', 2, 18, 55331.1),
(135, 'PLT08-25', 2, 18, 30.36),
(134, 'PLT08-25', 2, 18, 56.925),
(533, 'PLT08-25', 2, 18, 55.7865),
(93, 'PLT08-25', 2, 18, 56.925),
(4081, 'PLT08-437', 1, 18, 5206.74),
(4241, 'PLT08-437', 2, 18, 5206.74),
(4242, 'PLT08-437', 3, 18, 5206.74),
(4532, 'PLT08-437', 4, 18, 4946.656),
(24344, 'PLT08-437', 5, 18, Null),
(460, 'PLT10-574', 0, 18, 198207.284),
(943, 'PLT10-574', 2, 18, 198207.284),
(1248, 'PLT10-574', 3, 18, 198207.284),
(2371, 'PLT10-574', 4, 18, 198207.284),
(6173, 'PLT10-574', 5, 18, 198207.284),
(17787, 'PLT10-574', 6, 18, 198207.284),
(23533, 'PLT10-574', 7, 18, 198207.284)
;
```

And here is the expected result of the query I'm seeking:

```
RecordId    RootId  SubId   Fuel    Capacity
6111    PLT03-39    7   1   4399.67
6113    PLT03-40    7   1   14767.61
6110    PLT03-41    10  1   22850.96
6109    PLT03-42    7   1   9120.65
6112    PLT03-43    8   1   7711.44
381 PLT05-25    2   18  51854.88
7398    PLT06-143   3   18  4091.01
7397    PLT06-145   3   18  4091.01
13264   PLT06-342   6   1   30360
13271   PLT06-344   7   1   10120
22759   PLT06-87    6   6   143.451
24584   PLT07-234   4   18  2488.508
7664    PLT07-328   4   1   19607.5
5282    PLT07-39    5   18  50258.45
93  PLT08-25    2   18  56.925
24344   PLT08-437   5   18  4946.656
23533   PLT10-574   7   18  198207.284
```

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle

Comment: FYI, I realized (when trying to create a DDL + DML) that the sample data has some duplicate RecordId values.  Working to fix that now, and to provide a DDL + DML.

Comment: Question edited. I both corrected the data, and put it in the DDL/DML format.  And I added the expected output.

Comment: That's much better. +1. Most recent is determined by RecordId?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is one solution to this problem. I used a [CTE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) and [MAX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/max-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) aggregate to determine the latest `RecordId` for each `RootId`. After joining that back to the Plant table used an [OUTER APPLY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) to retrieve the most recent capacity.

```
WITH LATEST AS
(
    SELECT RootId, MAX(RecordId) AS RecordId
    FROM Plant
    GROUP BY RootId
)

SELECT
    P.RecordId
    , P.RootId
    , P.SubID
    , P.Fuel
    , CAP.Capacity
FROM
    LATEST AS L
    JOIN Plant AS P
        ON L.RecordId = P.RecordId
    OUTER APPLY
        (
            SELECT TOP 1 Capacity
            FROM Plant
            WHERE RootId = P.RootId AND Capacity IS NOT NULL
            ORDER BY SubID DESC
        ) AS CAP
ORDER BY
    L.RootId
```